# Difference between within and withincode designators in AspectJ

Tags: aop, aspectj, aspect

I am new to Aspect oriented programming. In this context, I have been going through a few designators, in which I found two designators "within" and "withincode". I could not understand their difference.  Can anyone please explain with a simple example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nándor's answer is correct, you should accept + upvote it. I just want to add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a simple example illustrating what he just explained so well. I am doing this for the benefit of other users who may find this question in the future in order to help them understand better what was described here theoretically.

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  private int id;
  private String name;

  public Application(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Application[id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
  }

  public void printName() {
    System.out.println(this);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Application(11, "My application").printName();
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Application;

public aspect WithinVsWithincodeAspect {
  before() : withincode(* Application.printName()) {
    System.out.println("[withincode] " + thisJoinPoint);
  }

  before() : within(Application) {
    System.out.println("[within]     " + thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
[within]     staticinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.Application.<clinit>)
[within]     execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[]))
[within]     call(de.scrum_master.app.Application(int, String))
[within]     preinitialization(de.scrum_master.app.Application(int, String))
[within]     initialization(de.scrum_master.app.Application(int, String))
[within]     execution(de.scrum_master.app.Application(int, String))
[within]     set(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.id)
[within]     set(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.name)
[within]     call(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.printName())
[within]     execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.printName())
[withincode] get(PrintStream java.lang.System.out)
[within]     get(PrintStream java.lang.System.out)
[withincode] call(void java.io.PrintStream.println(Object))
[within]     call(void java.io.PrintStream.println(Object))
[within]     execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.toString())
[within]     call(java.lang.StringBuilder(String))
[within]     get(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.id)
[within]     call(StringBuilder java.lang.StringBuilder.append(int))
[within]     call(StringBuilder java.lang.StringBuilder.append(String))
[within]     get(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.name)
[within]     call(StringBuilder java.lang.StringBuilder.append(String))
[within]     call(StringBuilder java.lang.StringBuilder.append(String))
[within]     call(String java.lang.StringBuilder.toString())
Application[id=11, name=My application]
```

As you can see, `within()` matches a super-set of joinpoints compared to `withincode()`. Of course you can combine both pointcuts with others via `&&` in order to narrow down the set of matched joinpoints even further or expand it via `||`. Exclusion via `!` is also possible, of course.

Please further note that `withincode()` matches what happens inside the target method but not the method execution itself. In this regard it is similar to `cflowbelow()` but it would not match anything outside of that method called from there as `cflow()` and `cflowbelow()` do.

Comment: You are a gentleman as always, Alex, but OP could just as well accept your answer because it's even better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

From the [AspectJ Programming Guide - Language Semantics - Pointcuts](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html)

> `within(TypePattern)`
>   *Picks out each join point where the executing code is defined in a type matched by TypePattern.*
>   `withincode(MethodPattern)`
>   *Picks out each join point where the executing code is defined in a method whose signature matches MethodPattern*.

With `within`, you can only restrict to a type, so without further restrictions, it will match any join points within the matching types. On the other hand, using `withincode`, you can use a pattern that narrows possible matching join points further, to the level of methods.

At the end of the page I linked, there is an EBNF summary about the grammar for the patterns used in the document.